# How to supply values using command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to supply values using below command.

This is my command

PS C:\Users\mydesktop\Desktop> . .\autoemail.ps1 -To 'sample.email.com'

This is the paramenter that need value.

cmdlet Send-MailMessage at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
To[0]:

Answer (score 0):

You might pass all the "[Accept pipeline input](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage#parameters)" ([valuefrompipelinebypropertyname](https://learn.microsoft.com/el/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument)) properties by outputting a [PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject) with the same property names:

**.\autoemail.ps1**

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    From       = 'sample@email.com'
    To         = 'sample@email.com'
    Subject    = 'The email subject!' 
    Body       = 'This is the body'
    SmtpServer = 'smtpserver.com'
    Credential = Get-Credential
}
```

Syntax:

```
.\autoemail.ps1 | Send-MailMessage
```